# Separate strings based on another dataset

Tags: sql, r, sas

I want to separate a character variable *fruit* in dataset *have* with the *name* from another dataset *namefile*(huge dataset).

The dataset *have* have 3 obs and 2 var(id, fruit). The var *fruit* may only contains one or more than one fruit names and those fruit names stored in the dataset *namefile*.

```
data have;
  input id fruit $ 20.;
datalines;
1 apple
2 pearapplebanana
3 BananaPear
;
data namefile;
  input name $ 20.;
datalines;
apple
pear
peach
banana
mango
;
```

For example, the second obs in have contains three fruit(pear, apple, banana) that can be found in the *namefile*. Then I want it duplicate into three obs and each obs contain one fruit only with the same id.

```
id   fruit
1    apple
2    pear
2    apple
2    banana
3    banana
3    pear
```

The result dataset will have 3 obs for id=2 and 2 obs for id=3. Please let me know if the question is clear or not.

Btw, the dataset contains the name is a big one like a dictionary.

Comment: What did you try? How did it not work for you?

Comment: @Tom It doesn't work. I guess my question is not clear enough and I have improved it. Hope this time it understandable.

Comment: 'if index(fruit, “apple") > 0 then output;' If there is a way can replace "apple" inside index function into the whole column 'name' from 'namefile', then job done.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a better way than that suggested by @Tom, however you seriously need to address the process that creates the data in the first place.  If the fruit names were separated by a delimiter then the process would be far easier, just using the `SCAN` function.  With your current format you run the risk of getting incorrect data if, for example, you had both 'apple' and 'pineapple' in the list of fruits.

Comment: @Keith, you right! If the fruit names have delimiter will make it much easier but the raw data I have doesn't. So I guess I have to take that risk of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files are small enough then just let PROC SQL compare every row in both files to each other.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select * 
    from have, namefile
    where index(upcase(fruit),upcase(trim(name)))
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would want better formatting of your have dataset. If that is not possible, I would transpose this dataset to get those ids as columns with fruit values in the data. Merge onto namefile, and check for if name is contained within fruit.

Note that without a var to merge by, SAS will guess and only merge on the first row. So make a dummy merge var. Here's the code I have. Sloppy - but it suits your needs. My output dataset matches yours exactly.

```
data have;
  input id fruit $ 20.;
mergeme=1;
datalines;
1 apple 
2 pearapplebanana
3 BananaPear
;
run;

data _null_;
  set have end=eof;
  if eof then call symputx ("LASTHAVEID",_n_);
run;

proc transpose data=have out=t_have(drop=_name_);
by mergeme;
var fruit;
id id;
run;

data namefile;
  input name $ 20.;
mergeme=1;
datalines;
apple
pear
peach
banana
mango
;
run;

data merged;
  merge t_have namefile;
  by mergeme;
run;

%macro createDS;
  data final(rename=(name=fruit));
    set merged;

    %do i=1 %to &LASTHAVEID.;
      if index(compress(upcase(_&i.)),compress(upcase(name)))>0 then do; id=&i.; output; end;
      drop _&i.;
    %end;
    drop mergeme;
  run;
%mend createDS;
%createDS;

proc sort data=final; by id fruit; run;
```

**EDIT:**
Made more dynamic for any number of rows in the have dataset with createDS macro.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I guess I have to improve my questions. What I need is separate the fruit name and duplicate the obs in have. I ran your codes but it doesn't gives the results that I want. Below link is the result of your codes. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWnhAHLkXCQRl84anZiQkNaM0E

Comment: @Leon it looks like the data you posted is the "merged" dataset. Make sure to also run the createDS macro I have to output dataset "final", or you'll have some useless merged data.

Either way created a much more elegant solution! As long as performance is good (and I expect it to be better than mine), I'd go with that. Just another reminder I need to step up my SQL.

Comment: I see! I didn't run the createDS macro and that's the reason.